# How to understand song titles like: "Hit me off"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, slang, lyrics

I'm listening R&B and would like to know what singer says.

Google translator cannot help and and [linguee](https://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=auto&query=%22hit%20me%20off%22) has no records.

How should I understand "hit me off" in [the lyrics for the New Edition song "Hit me off"](https://genius.com/New-edition-hit-me-off-lyrics)? (The last song [on this list](https://itunes.apple.com/at/album/hit-me-off/1032866037?i=1032867799&app=itunes), Nr. 38)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you found, this is not an idiom in common use, so we can assume this is something the songwriter made up because it sounds good.  In such a situation you have to interpret the meaning from context.

My guess is that here "hit me off" means more or less the same thing as "turn me on".

> [**turn (someone) on**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/turn-someone-on): to cause someone to feel excited and very interested.

This often has a *sexual* connotation, as in the singer would like the woman to make him feel *sexually excited*, and probably also that the singer would like the woman to agree to have sex with him.

Answer (score 1):

In this lyric from the 'Lil Wayne song "Cry Out", the phrase **hit me off** seems to be synonymous with the slang phrase "brush {someone} off", that is, to show no real respect or regard for them, to treat them as casually as a bug brushed off a sleeve. But you should get an answer from someone who is much more familiar with black vernacular speech than I am:

```
And all I know 'bout my real pops is that he had money 
No bank account, that brown paper bag money
Yea he might hit me off with a little brag money
But the nigga still wouldn't be a dad for me
```

Comment: It sounds more similar to the expression "buy someone off", meaning to try and win someone's favor with monetary gifts.  Although this usually implies some kind of *corruption*, and isn't normally used for family relationships.

Answer (score -1):

It's just my opinion but I think

> hit me off

is a bit of a play on

> hit it off

as in

> Person x and person y really hit it off last night!

I think the singer is saying he wants to hit it off with this girl.